# Select last row from csv in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, csv, azure-data-factory

I'm pulling in a small ( less than 100kb ) dataset as csv. All I want to do is select the last row of that data and sink it into a different location.

I cannot seem to find a simple way to do this.

I have tried a wrangling data flow, but the "keep rows" M function is not supported - though you can select it, it just results in an error. That's annoying because it does exactly what I need in one fell swoop.

I sort of get it working using a last() function on each field, but that is a lot of messing around and it's slow.

Surely there is a better way to do this simple task?

Would greatly appreciate any assistance.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mapping Data Flows: Surrogate Key, Aggregate (max), Filter (max row)

Comment: Thanks. If I follow you correctly you are saying to use surrogate key to index the records, then use aggregate to find the record with the highest number then select that record with filter. Is that correct? I'm trying this now and stuck on the aggregate task. I can't see how to preserve my other columns through aggregate.. my index column from the surrogate key is named "count", I can select that one using max(count), but all the other columns are dropped. Any ideas?

Comment: you can create 'New Branch'  after `Surrogate Key`,and inner join the branch and aggregate,join conditions 'count == max(count)',finally use 'Select' to remove columns which you don't need.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Really appreciate it and got it all working. BUT.. oh my that's a lot of work just to get the last row of information from a .csv The sooner that wrangling data flows support "keep bottom row(s)" the better.